# Excel - Keeping a running total based on a name

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I sorted data by name in Excel and if the name is the same as in the row above it I want to add 1 to another column.  If the name is not the same I want to reset the other column to 1.  I am tracking the # of students by teacher name.  An example would be if C3=C2 add 1 to D2 (based on what's in D2) and place it in D3, where C2 = Johns, C3 = Johns and D2=1 so D3 should add 1 to D2 and be 2.  In D4, C4=Jones so D4 = 1 (start over at 1 when there is a different name).  Can this be done in Excel?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Start with this formula in cell D2 and copy down

```
=IF(C2<>C1,1,D1+1)
```

[image]

Another option to get a head count per teacher is to use a pivot table. The data does not need to be sorted for that.  Click inside the data, then click Insert > Pivot table. Drag the Teacher into the Rows panel and drag the Teacher again into the Values panel to get a count.

[image]